# How to set a new version number in a .deb package I've built

Tags: debian, compiling, dpkg, dhcpcd

I've just completed a simple source code modification & rebuild on a Raspberry Pi OS - bullseye machine. Because this is new to me, I'll list the steps I followed in an effort to avoid ambiguity:

```bash
$ dhcpcd --version
dhcpcd 8.1.2                            # "before" version
$ sudo apt install devscripts           # build tools for using `debuild`
$ apt-get source dhcpcd5                # creates source tree ~/dhcpcd5-8.1.2; Debian git repo is far off!
$ cd dhcpcd5-8.1.2                      # cd to source dir
$ nano src/dhcp.c                       # make required changes to the source (one line)
~/dhcpcd5-8.1.2 $ debuild -b -uc -us    # successful build
$ cd ..
$ sudo dpkg -i dhcpcd5_8.1.2-1+rpt5_armhf.deb # install .deb file created by debuild
$ dhcpcd --version
dhcpcd 8.1.2                            # "after" version
$
```

All well & good, but the "before" & "after" version numbers are exactly the same, which leaves me without a simple way to know whether I have my *corrected* code running, or the *un-corrected* code. I'll install the  *corrected* .deb file to several hosts, I may get requests from others, etc, so I'd like ***some way*** to easily distinguish *corrected* from *un-corrected* code.

Using `dhcpcd --version` seems an easy way to do this. I've read that Debian has rules re version numbers, but as I'm not releasing this to "the world" I see no need for formality. Also - I've submitted a pull request/merge request to the Debian repo, and I've advised the RPi organization on the issue. I've gotten no feedback from either party, but this bug is a huge annoyance for me. I don't wish to wait for a new release of `dhcpcd` with a "proper" version number.

What must I do to cause the *corrected* version of `dhcpcd` to report `dhcpcd 8.1.2.1` - or something similar?

##### EDIT for Clarification:

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698621/286615), I edited `dhcpcd5-8.1.2/debian/changelog`. Following this change, the `apt` utilities consistently report the version of `dhcpcd` as `8.1.3`:

```bash
$ apt-cache policy dhcpcd5
dhcpcd5:
  Installed: 1:8.1.3-1+rpt1
  Candidate: 1:8.1.3-1+rpt1
  Version table:
 *** 1:8.1.3-1+rpt1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:8.1.2-1+rpt1 500
        500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages
     7.1.0-2 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages
$ #
$ dpkg -s dhcpcd5 | grep Version
Version: 1:8.1.3-1+rpt1 
$
```

However: `dhcpcd --version` still reports `8.1.2`. `dhcpcd` is aliased to `dhcpcd5` in `/etc/alternatives`. Consequently, `dhcpcd --version` is actually `dhcpcd5 --version`. It *appears* that the executable `dhcpcd5` is getting its `--version` from a different source than than `apt` utilities.?

##### EDIT 2:

Turns out the version # that gets reported by `dhcpcd --version` is defined in `defs.h` as follows:

```
#define PACKAGE                 "dhcpcd"
#define VERSION                 "8.1.2"
```

I *think* `dhcpcd` is a bit of an *outlier*. The RPi team apparently decided to forego the upstream version 9 when released (years ago), and have stuck to version 8.1.2 even though there were several upstream releases following ver 8.1.2. Still more confusing is the fact that the `.dsc` file lists `Vcs-Browser: https://salsa.debian.org/smlx-guest/dhcpcd5` as the Git repo - but it's actually stuck at version 7. This doesn't make much sense to me - I guess that's one reason I'm not a package maintainer.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either add the relevant lines at the top of `debian/changelog` (find [here](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dpkg-dev/deb-changelog.5.en.html) details on the contents of that file).

You can duplicate the current top stanza and change the version number (making an useful log comment is a good idea).

Alternatively you can use the `dch` tool (from `devtools`):

```
dch --local your_package_name
```

Once installed, you can check the installed version of the package with something like this (there are [alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15452/how-can-i-find-the-version-number-of-an-installed-package-via-dpkg))

```
dpkg -l dhcpcd5
```

Upstream version identifiers cannot be automatically imported because they don't always officially exist (say [python3-lzss](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/python3-lzss)) and when they do, they might not be compatible with the restrictions and sorting of the [package system versions](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#version). For example `epoch` is needed sometimes to migrate from upstream to Debian versions.

Comment: That does not seem to work. I edited `debian/changelog`. I copied the earlier entry, added it to the top of the file, then carefully edited it. The .deb file produced was `dhcpcd5_8.1.2.1-1+rpt1_armhf.deb`, but after `dpkg -i ...` `dhcpcd --version` still reports 8.1.2. Also tried changing to 8.1.3 => `dhcpcd5_8.1.3-1+rpt1_armhf.deb`, but `dhcpcd --version` still reports 8.1.2.

Comment: Tried `dch --local dhcpcd` with the same result as direct editing `debian/changelog`. My manual edits were bumped down 1 place, I re-edited, but got the same result. `dhcpcd` still thinks it is 8.1.2 - but it's not. I can see the difference my patch made, and a patched version is running.

Comment: @Seamus The package version and the tool-which-is-packaged-within version are two separate things. To change the tool's version you must edit its sources. For each tool that would be a different manner, each time requiring to read and understand its source.

Comment: @A.B: Yes - I have just figured that out :P   And I suppose that makes this a 2-part answer. Eduardo's answer was for a question I didn't actually ask, but part of the solution nevertheless. Would you like to post your answer for an upvote?

Comment: Short of finding out where the version number is set for the application (in some cases it might be on a library built from the same source), the way to have **some way to easily distinguish** (your question) is to do a `dpkg -l dhcpcd5`. Changing the version in the source *and* in the package can be time consuming and error prone if you just want to easily find out the binary you are running.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo - I guess I am the last person on the planet to learn that the process of building a `.deb` package doesn't automatically flow version info from the `debuild` process back into the source code. I'm not good w/ `C` - I assumed there was a macro or env var that took care of that. `dpkg -l` is also very useful. FWIW, I feel your answer would be improved & potentially more useful by adding some of the info here in the comments.